# Qt : Can a QMdiSubWindow be moved outside a QMdiArea and QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writting some kind of editor and I'd like to allow the user to move freely windows inside an MdiArea AND allow them to move the windows out of the MdiArea, out of the main window of the application.

How should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find a simple solution that works with Qt. It's not perfect as I didn't implement drag'n'drop but I guess it can be done too with a system similar to Visual Studio 2010 windows docking.

Here is the setup :

1. Make your widget class that is the content of the window -let's call it the document widget- inherit from something else than QDockWidget or QMdiSubWindow.
2. Now the document widget needs to own (create, keep and destroy) a QDockWidget, that will be the outside window, and a QMdiSubWindow, that will be the inside window. They need to be hidden both.
3. Assuming your main window have a QMdiArea in it's center, you'll have to add special code to register the inside window of your document in the QMdiArea.
4. Add a button somewhere (in the windows title bars or in the document widget) that trigger switching from the inside window to the outside window.
5. If we push that button and the document widget is in the inside window, we hide the inside window and then unregister the document widget from it. Then we register the document window int the outside window and show it.
6. To do the reverse, just do 5 with switching the outside and inside window.
7. you might have to add some special code to remove the document (meaning hide all windows and then unregister the inside window from the QMdiArea).

That way, the document widget will jump from a window inside the main window to a window outiside it without any problem, just by pushing a button.

---

I'm implementing this solution in an open source project. Once done and public I'll put links here.

edit: I've but my WIP `FreeWindowManager.hpp` implementation there (check the associated classes): https://code.google.com/archive/p/mjklaim-freewindows/source/default/source?page=2

Comment: Hi I'm trying to do this in pyqt4. I don't understand what you mean by register and deregister the document. Do you that I should make one widget with everything I want to show and set that widget to a qmdisubwindow or qdockwidget as required? But then what do you mean by deregister?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I want to say that such behavior should be avoided as it will be confusing to user. There are other methods of achieving such behavior (eg. toolbars).

I think you need to think about logic of your problem - dragging window out causes "unpinning" your window from main window, therefore your mdi child becomes regular toplevel window. Then draging it around should cause pinnig back at some point. You should define when exactly this unpinning and pinnng back should occur - when mdi chidld reaches edge of mdi area? or perhaps when cursor leaves mdi area while still dragging? Exact answer will be dependent on answer to this question.

One way of another, most likely you will need to create QMdiSubWindow descendant and reimplement QMdiSubWindow::moveEvent to check if "unpinnig" move was performed, and if so, call setParent(0) on widget embedded in QMdiSubWindow. Then your widget should also reimplement moveEvent for checking if it should be pinned back (if it already isn't that is) and creating new instance of your QMdiSubWindow descendant (if you `delete`'d it on unpinning), or use setWidget on stored copy of your QMdiSubWindow descendant (if you haven't `delete`'d it on unpinning).

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your first line, about the toolbars. Can you explain more about this?

Comment: I meant that if you want to have window that docks to your window but can also be freely dragged around desktop, then perhaps what you want is QDockWidget?

Comment: That's what I first thought but I don't see how to allow a QDockWidget to be able to be in a central widget of a main window. I tried with a QTabWidget as central widget but then it wouldn't allow to see several windows at the same time. Any advice? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is quite weird for me... Are you bascially trying to get two separate window spaces (desktop and your MDI area) with possibility of dragging windows between them? This so untypical that I don't think Qt supports it in any way. The only way to get it I see, is my original answer, but I think you might get into trouble with reparenting currently dragged window. This would need rewriting entire D&D mechanics of qt I'm afraid... If I were you i would really reconsider doing it other way.

Comment: BTW: I also don't know if what you are doinfg doesn't contain some logical error - what if window is on your MDI-area but is not embedded in it? Such behavior might be quite confusing to user. You might consider simply adding some options in menu or even additional button on sub-window bar to pin- and un-pin window, and leave drag&drop alone.

Comment: The perfect behaviour would be how the Visual Studio 2010 dockable/floating windows behave - it's erally powerful in particular when working with several screens.. Try it to see what I want to achieve, but I think you're right, it will be hard to setup in Qt. VS2010 allow windows to be docked (with a specific display appearing when you move the window in some aread and you can dock to one of it's dockable areas; and it also allow docked window to be moved out simply by not moving them in another dockable area.

Comment: In fact, the QDockWidget present exactly the same behaviour. There is one problem though : QDockWidgets can only be docked in specific areas of the QMainWindow. I cannot find a way to add the central part or some system to get QDockWidget to dock in the central part. There is one ugly (visually) solution : Have a central QMdiArea, then put QDockWidgets in it. That will create QMdiSubWindows for each QDockWidgets. Then, you can put the QDockWidget out of the QMdiSubWindow. I tried that and that makes the QMdiSubWindow empty.

Comment: Maybe I can find an easy way to close the QMdiSubWindow once the QDockWidget is out, then re-inject the QDockWidget in the MdiArea when I, say, push a specific button in the DockWindow title bar? I'll try this.

Comment: I run linux so i cannot really test Visual Studio 2010 to see what you mean. Anyway if I understand you right, draging in and out of MDI area would be confusing, and you should really consider alternatives. Does VS2010 allow to drag windows in and out of central widget? Are those windows classical mdi chi;dren?

Comment: When you move windows out of docking or from the central area, some buttons representing possible docking areas appear (central too). If you drop in one of these buttons, the window get docked in that area. If you do not drop there, it will make you window floating. There is also a button to switch from floating/docking. I think I'll do that. When you have two or more wide screens, it means you can put some of the windows, like the debug ouput, code windows,  or other useful views, on other screens than the VS2010 screen. That's incredibely useful.

Comment: Here is a video that show a bit of the feature - it's not confusing at all. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lR2Pf9YH4Fo However it doesn't show how you can drag the window back in a specific docking area. I'm using several screens and I find it very powerful and intuitive.

Comment: I admit - this looks nice and useful. Unfortunately it's not the first time I notice that qt seems to be quite "closed" environment - they have they own way of doing things, and it's encoded deeply into their code. Modification is impossible without modyfynig internals of library - which in case of qt is impossible if you want to share it. The only way is to "fork" their solution - download qt source, copy relevant classes, rename them and modify to your needs. I need to add that Qt classes are so deeply bounded with each other that it is usually quicker to write entire susbsystem from scratch

Comment: I managed to get it working in a simple setup with Qt, I'll create an answer to my question.

Comment: Not sure why it would be confusing. If the user drags a subwindow to location x, how would it be confusing if the subwindow actually moved to location x? Could this be an instance of the common developer malady: "This is hard within my framework, therefore you shouldn't want to do it"? That said, this sounds more like SDI than MDI.

Comment: @neuronet What I mean by confusing: imagine that window can be inside MDI window but not maximized - then it has window bar and so on, so it looks exactly like top level window. What if your window was indeed a top-level window, but just happened to be positioned above your MDI window. How would user visually distinguish between those situations? How could user even request dragging such window into MDI are from top-level space - he would not receive any visual confirmation that it became MDI window.

Comment: @neuronet And about " and about "This is hard within my framework, therefore you shouldn't want to do it" - if you write a framework library, you have to design some principles it follows. If you go too broad, you will spend much of your time developing features that hardly anybody will ever use. It's not that you shouldn't want to do some things - but if you do, I (and my framework) are not going to help you. Perhaps you should think about a different framework?

Comment: @j_kubik very well put. If more developers explained it that way to end users, there would be much more love in this world.